# Absolute path in perl's copy command gone wrong?

Tags: windows, perl, file, path, copy

This is my very simple code, which isn't working, for some reason I can't figure out.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Copy;

$old = "car_lexusisf_gray_30inclination_000azimuth.png";
$new = "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\mycomp\simulation\cars\zzzorganizedbyviews\00inclination_000azimuth\lexuscopy.png";

copy ($old, $new)  or die "File cannot be copied.";
```

I get the error that the file can't be copied.

I know there's nothing wrong with the copy command because if I set the value of $new to  something simple without a path, it works. But what is wrong in the representation of the path as I've written it above? If I copy and past it into the address bar of windows explorer, it reaches that folder fine.

Comment: you need to backslash the backslash e.g `C:\\car...`

Comment: Or use forward slashes. That's usually the simplest solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tip: print out the paths before you perform the copy. You'll see this:

```
C:SERSenovodocumentsmycompsimulationrszzzorganizedbyviewsinclination_000azimuthexuscopy.png
```

Not what we wanted. The backslash is an escape character in Perl, which needs to be escaped itself. If the backslash sequence does not form a valid escape, then it's silently ignored. With escaped backslashes, your string would look like:

```
"C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Documents\\mycomp\\simulation\\cars\\zzzorganizedbyviews\\00inclination_000azimuth\\lexuscopy.png";
```

or just use forward slashes instead – in most cases, Unix-style paths work fine on Windows too.

Here is a list of escapes you accidentally used:

- `\U` uppercases the rest
- `\L` lowercases the rest
- `\ca` is a control character (ASCII 1, the *start of heading*)
- `\00` is an octal character, here the NUL byte
- `\l` lowercases the next character.

Answer (score 3):

If no interpolation is intended, use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: what do you mean by interpolation?

Comment: @user961627 - [interpolation](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html)